Does the volume of air in an air tight container affect food shelf life?
I'm specifically talking about storing tea bags here, but equally any other dried foods. I'm trying to switch to buying certain things in bulk, so I'm trying to understand some basic principles.
I understand that once I put foodstuffs in an airtight container, the air inside the container contains bacteria and mold floating in the air.
When the container is full of food, there is obviously still air in there, even is it is small.  And as you consume the food product, the air volume gets larger.
So my questions are:

Will a foodstuff, such as tea bags, go off or degrade quicker in a larger volume of air as the volume increases or does it not make much difference?  I could buy two or more smaller containers so that the air volume is much smaller once food is removed, or I could buy one large one.

If there is air in the container with bacteria and mold anyway, what benefit does an airtight container provide?



For this exact reason, I buy tea bags in multiple smaller packages.  Only one is open at a time (the rest still wrapped in their airtight(?) plastic).  But all are stored in a lunchbox.

Your question in general is a good one but the example of tea bags seems odd to me. As long as they stay dry tea bags don't ever go bad. For high quality tea the flavor is preserved better if it is stored in an airtight container but tea bags in general contain low quality tea.

Yes, but it’s not so much about mold and bacteria, but about oxygen.
Oxygen availability results in deterioration of some foods via chemical reactions.  Some packaged foods, especially those intended for long term storage (such as disaster preparedness meals) will either vacuum seal the package, ‘oxygen absorber’ packets to reduce this problem, fill the package with nitrogen to push out any oxygen, or a combination of these.
There are hard sided containers that have a one-way valve on them, so they can be connected to a vacuum to remove air, but this can cause problems for some foods (marshmallows are a classic example, as they will expand to fill the space).
One way to deal with your issue is to use more than one container.  You keep a smaller container that you’re opening for regular use, and then a larger container that only gets opened when you need to refill the smaller one.  This reduces the number of air changes that the food is exposed to before it’s used up.  To reduce it further, you can use multiple smaller containers, fill them as full as you can, then use up the remainder (not entirely full one) first.

Brilliant.  Thanks

"Oxygen availability results in deterioration of some foods via chemical reactions" You mean food oxidises?

Flushing food storage containers with nitrogen is a fairly common technique for people looking to have, say, a year's supply of food on hand.

@Clockwork : yes.  There are many types, though.  Enzymatic browning, fats going rancid, etc

I thought the absorbing packets you find in food are for moisture, not oxygen.

@MarkRansom : there are both.  Some are labeled with what they are.  (Others just say ‘do not eat’)

1. Degradation
Having a larger container with more air volume does not do much to the foodstuff inside. Especially if it is "dry" like tea bags, noodles, rice, etc. (A little different would be fresh food in a container for storing in the fridge, of course).
Tea for example is best stored in tin cans. The air tightening is only needed, if you do not like the odor/smell of the tea lingering in the air. Tea will stop smelling after long periods exposed to air, which might affect the taste (connoisseurs will care).
Keep in mind that plastic containers tend to take on smells (tea) and always stays smelling like that, even after washing thoroughly.
Metal boxes (stainless steel) does not take on smells or at least is easily neutralized with a little water and dish soap.
Glass containers work also nicely for rice, noodles, etc.
2. Usefulness
There are multiple benefits for containers:

prevents insects like flies, moths, spiders, ... reaching and infesting the food
allow easier stacking and storage
can be labeled, sorted by date of expiry, whatever you like
keeps odor/smell inside (see above in case of tea)
prevents moldy/spoiled food inside from spreading over to other food/containers. So you lose maybe only one container, not the whole stock. Considering the right size can greatly help reduce damage in such a case, but is a trade-off in storage space / cost etc. of course.
prevent food from getting humid or wet in the worst case.

For example, I use 5 liter airtight plastic containers to store multiple (2-3) packets of rice, noodles, dried beans etc. in it (separated per type). Mostly to fend of vermin/insects and for easier storage.

That's brilliant.  Thanks so much for explaining that.  Why use tins over say glass kilner jars?

In the case of tea: You want to protect it from UV-Light. So either use "brown glass", or just tin cans. "Clear" glass might also work, but I have no experience with it in case of tea. For noodles, rice etc. there is no problem, as I can see. For herbs brown glass is commonly used (could be a analogy to tea). I for one have clear glass for herbs. So the difference may be marginal.

Concerning tea: I also use one larger tin box (formerly from a cookie brand (filled), check you shop, might be a cheap way of acquiring those, they are not airtight, tho) and store the open boxes of tea inside there. This saves on expensive tin cans and is also convenient when picking one. The odor mixes a little inside, but does not come out (no degradation on taste noticeable).

Ok great. Thanks again.  The setup I'm going for is 1-2L kilner jars put inside a dark cupboard. Tea lives in there, then a 750ml tin can on the shelf for day to day use.

Sounds good! A dark space also helps of course.
